# How to merge two different object type in one object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting

```
callingmethod(){
File f=new File();  
//...
String s= new String();
//...

method( f + s);    // here is problem (most put f+s in object to send it to method)
}
```

cant change method args

```
method(Object o){
//...
//how to split it to file and String here 
}
```

for any thing not clear ask plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. put it in an array:

```
method (new Object[] {f, s});

void method (Object o) {
    final Object[] arr = (Object[]) o;
    File f = (File) arr[0];
    String s = (String) arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest and most idiomatic way is to create a simple class to represent your pair:

```
static class FileString {
  public final File f;
  public final String s;
  FileString(File f, String s) { 
    this.f = f; this.s = s;
  }
}
```

then write

```
method(new FileString(file, string));
```

inside method:

```
FileString fs = (FileString)o;
// use fs.f and fs.s
```

Depending on further details, use a nested class like in my example, or put it into its own file. If you keep it close to the place where you instantiate it, then you can make the constructor private or package-private, like I did. But these are just the finer details.